# Install Ubuntu 16 with text based and use ubuntu with no GUI

Tags: ubuntu, gui, text, aws

I have tried installing Ubuntu 16 with minimal cd and I'm getting the text based installation, but the thing is I want to install ubuntu only with text-based installation and after that, I want to use Ubuntu only with text-based (Same as Ubuntu Linux which is available in AWS - No GUI )
Can anyone help me to achieve this.?

Comment: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server for downloading, and https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server for installation instructions.

Comment: press ctrl-alt-f1, `apt purge xserver-xorg-core`

Comment: agreed - server install is the way to go.  For instance, Ubuntu 17.10 workstation install has a couple of serious issues which prevent installing directly; I used the text-based server install to get something that worked.  From that, you can install whatever is needed.

Comment: Thanks @Videonauth, I have installed ubuntu server and now i'm getting text based version ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a minimal install without a GUI you using [the minimale CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) or any Ubuntu CD, install ubuntu as usually , at the **Software Installation** step only select the **Standard software utilities** , it is also important to configure your system to receive the security updates automatically .

The 2 consecutive steps should be :

Configuring `tasksel`:

```
Install Security Updates automatically
```

Software selection :

```
standard system utilities
```

You can add more software such OpenSSH to control your system through `ssh`  .... but do not install the GUI.

Comment: Yes, @GAD3R I have installed ubuntu server same as you mentioned above